# \StrSubstitute doesn't work on the string produced by the \ref macro

Tags: xstring

In this LaTeX code I attempt to replace the "(" in references, so that they would look like "x)", not "(x)":

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{xstring}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*)]
\item \label{cla:Item1} an apple
\item \label{cla:Item2} a banana
\item a carrot, see \StrSubstitute{\ref{cla:Item1}}{(}{}
\item a durian, see \StrSubstitute{\ref{cla:Item2}}{(}{}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

However, \StrSubstitute doesn't seem to work and all references are still printed as "(x)".

Why \StrSubstitute doesn't work? Is this a bug?

Are there any workarounds?

Answer (score 3):

It cannot work, because `\ref` produces what's needed to *print* the reference.

It's easier.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*),ref=\alph*)]
\item \label{cla:Item1} an apple
\item \label{cla:Item2} a banana
\item a carrot, see \ref{cla:Item1}
\item a durian, see \ref{cla:Item2}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You *can* do it with `\StrSubstitute`, but you have to use `refcount` that provides an expandable version of `\ref` and remove two pairs of braces (or use slow features of `xstring` that examine things hidden in braces), because the reference returned by `\ref{cla:Itemi1}` is `{{(a)}}`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{refcount}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\getenumitemref}[1]{%
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\@firstofone
  \expandafter\@firstofone
  \expanded{\getrefbykeydefault{#1}{}{0}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*)]
\item \label{cla:Item1} an apple
\item \label{cla:Item2} a banana
\item a carrot, see \StrSubstitute{\getenumitemref{cla:Item1}}{(}{}
\item a durian, see \StrSubstitute{\getenumitemref{cla:Item2}}{(}{}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This answers my question, thank you!